# AWS SM State Manager: How are associations applied for instances created after initial association?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

The [AWS Systems Manager State Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-state.html) allows us to create associations between 'intents' and 'targets' - essentially mapping commands to instances.

I would like to create an association that will run for all instances in an ASG - such that new instances that get created when scaling-up, automatically run the commands specified in the State Manager document.

I can target all instances in an ASG by using the appropriate tag in the association (eg `Key=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=MyTargetGroup`) - but it's not clear if this will apply to new instances that don't exist yet. This is even less clear from the requirement to specify a "schedule expression" for the association.

From some tests it appears that new instances *do* in fact get the association applied, but I can't find any clear documentation explaining this, nor does it fit with the need for providing a "schedule expression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clearly documented, but any new instances that are created in the future **will** have a State Manager association applied if they are created with a targeted tag. The association runs almost instantly once the instance is running.

The schedule expression is an optional value to **also** apply the association at set time / interval.

From an [Amazon employee forum response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=280095):

> [A]ny new instance that's launched with that tag will have the
>   Association applied at launch. The schedule expression allows you to
>   apply the association even after the instance launch apply

Comment: Here's a good reference from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/state-manager-vs-maintenance-windows.html):

State Manager can monitor all new nodes launched within an account either manually or through Auto Scaling groups. If there are any associations in the account targeting that new node (through tags or all nodes), then that particular association is automatically applied to the new node.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of SSM Automation documents, the association will not run on new instances matching the Tags targeted. See this [official AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-state-manager-targets-and-rate-controls.html#systems-manager-state-manager-targets-and-rate-controls-about-targets:%7E:text=If%20you%20create%20new,uses%20an%20Automation%20runbook.) quoted below:

> If you create new nodes and assign the specified tag key and value to
> those nodes, the system automatically applies the association, runs it
> immediately, and then runs it according to the schedule. **This applies
> when the association uses a Command or Policy document and doesn't
> apply if the association uses an Automation runbook**.